# how to restrict content folder files to copy only to certain project in nuget install.ps1

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I have three .cs files in content folder of my nuget package. Now when this package get installed on a solution where there are multiple projects.

I need to reference this package almost all projects in that solution but I want to restrict these three .cs files only to particular project.

How to achieve that? Any strategy/idea/configuration/code?

Thanks

Comment: why not make an additional nuget package for the items you only want in a single project? if you need to hardcode dependencies again, there is no value in making reusable packages..

Comment: Thought about that but this package is being used by 20 other services and now if start carved out different package for diff features it would be one more package we have to manage which I think we can manage by handling the behavior through install.ps1 and only allow adding those files into a project which has starting format name of some kind